# Superfluids (meaning, properties)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, viscosity, superfluidity

I am curious as to what a superfluid is? I have seen videos that say that they have zero viscosity, and I know that it means that there is no friction between the layers of the fluid. But what is its impact on how the superfluid acts?
And, I know that a fluid like helium becomes a superfluid if you drop its temperature to a certain critical temperature. But, why does that drop make its viscosity zero? What is the microscopic explanation?
Also, I have seen videos of a superfluid coming out of a bowl. Some scientists in the videos said that it was from the superfluid that was climbing on the edges of the bowl. Why was it climbing? (microscopically).
Other scientists said that it kind of penetrates the bowl. Is it true? And if it actually is, how is it possible? What is the microscopic explanation?
Note that I do not know QM (just a few basic things). I will understand any QM explanation that you will give me as long as you make it accessible and give me some definitions that you will use!

Sorry for the multipart question!

Comment: Did you check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluidity)?

Comment: Yes,but it does not give answers to all of my questions.

Comment: Cross out the ones it does give you an answer to.

Comment: you are right.will do so.